# Camera screen freezes after going into power-saving mode

Tags: android, opencv, camera

For testing OpenCV with android, I installed a simple opencv app on my android. Everything seems OK. But one problem I can see is that once screen goes to power-saving mode, the app's screen stops responding. How can I resolve this matter? Do I have to turn the power-saving feature off when the camera is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need a wakelock (stops power saving), ensure you are releasing the camera resource in one of the lifecycle methods onPause() or onStop() then reacquire the camera resource in onResume().